# big problem to subdivide a face

Tags: faces, edges, subdivision-surface

impossible to subdivide the side that I have selected, there must be double sides, I have tried everything, on the other side of the chest, I can subdivide but on this side, it is impossible, I am leaving you the link of the model, explain me please, Thank You !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an ngon, subdivide will create vertices along its edges but won't cut the face with edges, because Blender can't guess how it is supposed to be divided.

Comment: that's what I had noticed there are sides, on the edges of my faces, but suddenly? how to do ?

Comment: You can subdivide, make the rest of your mesh invisible (Shift H), switch to Vertex Select Mode, join the opposite vertices with J or with the knife tool